# How do i find out what my codesign identity is?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

Last time i built my app for the app store i was using XCode 3, and am now using XCode 4. The code signing settings seem to have changed since then. Am i able to find out what settings I was using last time, through Member Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, your codesign-settings will be exactly like before, only easier to locate.

[Here is a useful guide on how to codesign with Xcode 4.](http://www.smartapps.co/2011/02/tutorial-code-signing-in-xcode-4/)